# mpy gives keeps raising error because of Protocol

Tags: python, protocols, mypy

Im using pytest framework with mypy and when writing fixtures I created Protocols to mimic return types. (I could not import it directly because of env instantiation)

This example greatly simplifies my troubles:

```
 from typing_extensions import Protocol

class LoadServiceType(Protocol):
    z: int

class LoadService:
    z: int

#This works as expected
load_serivce: LoadServiceType = LoadService()

# But now I dont know why this does not work
class FooType(Protocol):
    load_service: LoadServiceType
    
class Boo:
    x:int
    load_service:LoadService
    bb: int
    
    
cc: FooType = Boo()
```

Basically I want to use my FooType as a return type because of import issues. Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be represented by the following minimal example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Protocol


@dataclass
class Fooish:
    bar: int


class FooLike(Protocol):
    bar: float


foo: FooLike = Fooish(bar=321)
```

**mypy** raises the following error:

```bash
foo.py:18: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Fooish", variable has type "FooLike")  [assignment]
foo.py:18: note: Following member(s) of "Fooish" have conflicts:
foo.py:18: note:     bar: expected "float", got "int"
```

The `FooLike` protocol represents a set of objects which have a **writable float member** named `bar`. The `Fooish` class' `bar` member is an `int` and does not accept `float` values to be assigned, thus is incompatible.

According to `foo: FooLike`, the following should be valid, but isn't:

```
foo: FooLike = Fooish(bar=321)
foo.bar = 21.37
```

---

To fix the compatibility issue, one should define the variable as read-only via a `@property`:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Protocol


@dataclass
class Fooish:
    bar: int


class FooLike(Protocol):
    @property
    def bar(self) -> float:
        ...


foo: FooLike = Fooish(bar=321)
```

---

So, going back to your original example, the following snippet works as expected:

```py
from typing_extensions import Protocol


class LoadServiceType(Protocol):
    z: int


class LoadService:
    z: int


load_serivce: LoadServiceType = LoadService()


class FooType(Protocol):
    @property
    def load_service(self) -> LoadServiceType:
        ...


class Boo:
    x: int
    load_service: LoadService
    bb: int


cc: FooType = Boo()
```